# merge fields list in search kit

Tags: tokens

how to get ID of a relationship in Search Kit ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field was just not exposed and @coleman did a commit that will be active starting from version 5.39:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20558